# How to create a list in R for reproducible example question

Tags: r, list

I am trying to create a list for use in a reproducible example here which has structure (`Delta.Tmax`) that looks like this:
[image]

This is the code I've come up with so far:

```
#create data
tmintest=array(1:100, c(512,256,12))

#create the list
Variable <- list(varName = c("tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin"),level = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
Data     <- list(Data = tmintest)
xyCoords <- list(x = seq(-40.37,64.37,length.out=420), y = seq(25.37,72.37,length.out=189))
Dates <- list(start = seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), by="days"), end=seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), by="days"))
Delta <- list(Variable = Variable,Data=Data, xyCoords=xyCoords,Dates=Dates)
```

But as you can see, it is not the same:
[image]

`Delta Data` is expandable (where it shouldn't be). I have added `Delta Data` using this too:

```
Variable <- list(Data = tmintest,varName = c("tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin"),level = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

But then `Delta Data` is at the same level as `varName` and `level`. Also, it doesn't have that extra dimension in the Data that I see in `Delta.Tmax$Data`

[image]

Comment: Change `Data <- list(Data = tmintest)` to `Data <- tmintest`.

Comment: @GKi That worked perfectly thanks. Would you happen to know how I can find out about what the singleton dimension in `Delta.Tmax$Data` is? I can see the dimension using `dim(Delta.Tmax$Data)` and tried to find out about it `attr(Delta.Tmax$Data)` but `attr` is obviously the wrong command

Comment: Maybe you use `tmintest <- array(as.double(1:100), c(12,1,256,512))` ?